# Axis interaction using Dygraph

Tags: javascript, plot, dygraphs, axes

I have the following [plot at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cirrus01/qxps64ga/3/) that I am trying to put together using dygraph:

```
var data = [];

function getData() {
    data = [];
    var theDate = new Date(2012, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
        data.push([new Date(theDate.getTime()), Math.random()]);
        theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    g.updateOptions({
        'file': data
    });
}


var g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("div_g"), data, {
    drawPoints: true,
    showRoller: false,
    rollPeriod: 1,
    valueRange: [0.0, 1.2],
    labels: ['Time', 'Random'],
    xlabel: 'Time',
    ylabel: 'Random',
    legend: 'always',
    showRangeSelector: true
});

function change(el) {
    g.setVisibility(el.id, el.checked);
}

setInterval(
getData, 1000)
```

I would like to edit the axes limits on the fly by simple plot interaction (i.e. no use of text boxes, just use the canvas).  Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: You can hold down shift and click+drag to pan on any dygraph. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually, what I am looking for is something a little more granular (although this works also).  What I am interested in is direct interaction with the axis on the canvas, i.e. when the user double clicks on one of the limits, they can edit it and change it to a new limit.  This might be a bit much, but just thought I would put it out there.